# User interface for a simple tool that generates Word documents from Excel data

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, ms-word

This question provides the code behind the dialogs in the [C# refactoring question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272954/follow-up-refactored-c-tool-to-generate-ms-word-document-mailbox-list-from-ms). I'd like a review of this code as well. I'm not currently using databinding anywhere, and there is really only one place that it might help which is in the add or edit tenant form. This question is separate from the other question because there is too much code to present in one question.

Visual Studio generated code is not included in this question.

### Features

- Generate MS Word documents from the data in the Excel spreadsheet for use as directories by mailboxes.
- Add or Edit a tenant to the complex.
- Delete a tenant from the complex.
- Set preferences for when to save or print a file. Where to store saved Word documents. Where to find the Excel spreadsheet file.
- Save any current changes.
- The data is saved automatically when the program exits.
- If the Excel file is open in another application it warns the user and will not start. If the user open it in Excel after the program starts it warns them that the changes can't be saved until the Excel file is closed.

[image: RentRosterApp Form, the Control Panel]
[image: Print Mailbox List Dialog]
[image: Add or Edit Tenant Dialog]
[image: Delete Tenant Dialog]
[image: Edit Preferences Dialog]

### RentRosterApp.cs

This is the main form started by the Program.cs module, consider it a control panel, it only contains buttons that open other dialogs. It does however contain some program logic for global initialization.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class RentRosterApp : Form
    {
        private bool globalsInitialized;

        public RentRosterApp()
        {
            globalsInitialized = Globals.InitializeAllModels();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RentRosterApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RR_Quit_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (!globalsInitialized)
            {
                PrintMailboxLists_Button.Enabled = false;
                AddNewResident_Button.Enabled = false;
                DeleteRenter_Button.Enabled = false;

                using (EditPreferencesDlg preferences_dlg = new EditPreferencesDlg())
                {
                    if (preferences_dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        PrintMailboxLists_Button.Enabled = true;
                        AddNewResident_Button.Enabled = true;
                        DeleteRenter_Button.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void PrintMailboxLists_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintMailboxListsDlg printMailboxLists_dialog = new PrintMailboxListsDlg();
            printMailboxLists_dialog.Show();
        }

        private void AddNewResident_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApartmentNumberVerifier verifier_Form = new ApartmentNumberVerifier();
            verifier_Form.NextAction = ApartmentNumberVerifier.NextActionEnum.ADD;
            verifier_Form.Show();
        }

        private void DeleteRenter_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApartmentNumberVerifier verifier_Form = new ApartmentNumberVerifier();
            verifier_Form.NextAction = ApartmentNumberVerifier.NextActionEnum.DELETE;
            verifier_Form.Show();
        }

        private void EditPreferences_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditPreferencesDlg preferences_dlg = new EditPreferencesDlg();
            preferences_dlg.Show();
        }

        private void RR_Quit_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Globals.Save();
                Globals.ReleaseAllModels();
                Close();
            }
            catch (AlreadyOpenInExcelException ao)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ao.Message);
            }
        }

        private void RR_SAVEEDITS_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Globals.SaveTenantData();
            }
            catch (AlreadyOpenInExcelException ao)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ao.Message);
            }
        }

        private void RentRosterApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Save all changes before quiting.
            Globals.Save();
            Globals.ReleaseAllModels();
        }
    }
}
```

### EditPreferencesDlg.cs

This form allows the users to edit their preferences, it is called with a button on the main control panel, but if the preferences have never been created before then the control panel opens it automatically. There might be a fairly strong coupling between this class and the `UserPreferences` class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class EditPreferencesDlg : Form
    {
        private UserPreferences localPreferences;

        public EditPreferencesDlg()
        {
            localPreferences = new UserPreferences();
            localPreferences.CopyValues(Globals.Preferences, true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EditPreferencesDlg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EP_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
            EP_SavePreferences_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
            EP_DefaultFileFolder_TB.Text = localPreferences.DefaultSaveDirectory;
            EP_RentRosterLocation_TB.Text = localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec;
            EP_SheetName_TB.Text = localPreferences.ExcelWorkSheetName;
            switch (localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions)
            {
                case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave:
                    EP_PrintAndSave_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly:
                    EP_SavelOnly_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    EP_PrintOnly_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;
            }
            EP_SheetName_TB.Enabled = false;
            EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX.Visible = false;
        }

        private void EP_PrintAndSave_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave;
        }

        private void EP_SavelOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly;
        }

        private void EP_PrintOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly;
        }

        private void EP_DefaultFileFolder_TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.DefaultSaveDirectory = EP_DefaultFileFolder_TB.Text;
        }

        private void findDefaultFolderLocationExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

                if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                {
                    EP_DefaultFileFolder_TB.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
                    localPreferences.DefaultSaveDirectory = fbd.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
        }

        private void EP_DefaultFileFolder_TB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            findDefaultFolderLocationExecute(sender, e);
        }

        private void EP_BrowseFolderLocation_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            findDefaultFolderLocationExecute(sender, e);
        }

        private void EP_RentRosterLocation_TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec = EP_RentRosterLocation_TB.Text;
        }

        private void findTenantRosterExcelFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tenantRosterFile = "";
            OpenFileDialog FindTenantRoster = new OpenFileDialog();
            FindTenantRoster.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            FindTenantRoster.Filter = "Excel Files| *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm";
            if (FindTenantRoster.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tenantRosterFile = FindTenantRoster.FileName;
                EP_RentRosterLocation_TB.Text = tenantRosterFile;
                localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec = tenantRosterFile;
            }
        }

        private void fillSheetSelectorListBox()
        {
            List<string> sheetNames = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec))
            {
                ExcelFileData ExcelFile = new ExcelFileData(localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec,
                    localPreferences.ExcelWorkSheetName);
                sheetNames = ExcelFile.GetWorkSheetCollection();
            }

            if (sheetNames == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX.DataSource = sheetNames;
            EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX.Visible = true;
            EP_SheetName_TB.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void EP_FindRenterRoster_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            findTenantRosterExcelFile(sender, e);
            fillSheetSelectorListBox();
        }

        private void EP_RentRosterLocation_TB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            findTenantRosterExcelFile(sender, e);
            fillSheetSelectorListBox();
        }
        private void EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localPreferences.ExcelWorkSheetName = EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX.SelectedItem.ToString();
            EP_SheetName_TB.Text = localPreferences.ExcelWorkSheetName;
        }

        private void EP_SheetName_TB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillSheetSelectorListBox();
        }

        private void EP_SavePreferences_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Make sure any previous edits to the tenant are saved
            // then reset all the models.
            Globals.Save();
            Globals.ReInitizeAllModels(localPreferences);
            Globals.SavePreferences();
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Close();
        }

        private void EP_Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

### PrintMailboxListsDlg.cs

This form allows the user to print and or save word documents created from the excel data. It also allows the user to override some of their preferences on a case by case basis.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class PrintMailboxListsDlg : Form
    {
        private PrintSavePreference.PrintSave printSave;
        private bool addDateToFileName = false;
        private bool addDateToTitle = false;
        private string selectedBuildings;
        private MSWordInterface wordInteropMethods;

        public PrintMailboxListsDlg()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            wordInteropMethods = new MSWordInterface(Globals.Preferences);
        }

        private void PrintMailboxLists_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> buildings = Globals.Complex.BuildingAddressList;

            foreach (string building in buildings)
            {
                SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.Items.Add(building);
            }
            SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.Items.Add("All Buildings");

            if (Globals.Preferences.HavePreferenceData)
            {
                printSave = Globals.Preferences.PrintSaveOptions;
                PrintSaveChange();
            }

            AddDateToFileName_CB.Checked = addDateToFileName;
            AddDateUnderAddress_CB.Checked = addDateToTitle;
            PML_SaveAndPrint_Button.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void AddDateToFileName_CB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addDateToFileName = !addDateToFileName;
        }

        private void AddDateUnderAddress_CB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addDateToTitle = !addDateToTitle;
        }

        private void PML_SaveAndPrint_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.Compare(selectedBuildings, "All Buildings") == 0)
            {
                List<int> StreetNumbers = Globals.Complex.StreetNumbers;

                foreach (int streetNumber in StreetNumbers)
                {
                    printAndOrSaveMailList(streetNumber);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string streetAddress = selectedBuildings.Substring(0, 5);
                printAndOrSaveMailList(streetAddress);
            }

            Close();
        }

        private void printAndOrSaveMailList(string streetAddress)
        {
            int iStreetNumber = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(streetAddress, out iStreetNumber))
            {
                printAndOrSaveMailList(iStreetNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Non Numeric string passed into PrintMailboxLists_Form::printAndOrSaveMailList().");
            }
        }

        private void PML_PrintOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printSave = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly;
        }

        private void PML_SavelOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printSave = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly;
        }

        private void PML_PrintAndSave_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printSave = PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave;
        }

        private void PrintSaveChange()
        {
            switch (printSave)
            {
                case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave:
                    PML_PrintAndSave_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;

                case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly:
                    PML_SavelOnly_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    PML_PrintOnly_RB.Checked = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void SelectBuilding2Print_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                selectedBuildings = SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                PML_SaveAndPrint_Button.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void printAndOrSaveMailList(int streetAddress)
        {
            bool save = ((printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave) ? true :
                (printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly) ? true : false);
            bool print = ((printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave) ? true :
                (printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly) ? true : false);

            string documentName = "MailboxList_" + streetAddress;

            string statusMessage = (print && save) ? "Printing and Saving " :
                (print) ? "Printing " : "Saving ";
            statusMessage += "the mailbox list for " + streetAddress;

            ReportCurrentStatusWindow psStatus = new ReportCurrentStatusWindow();
            psStatus.MessageText = statusMessage;
            psStatus.Show();

            Building building = Globals.Complex.GetBuilding(streetAddress);
            if (building != null)
            {
                MailboxData mailboxList = Globals.Complex.GetMailBoxList(building);
                if (mailboxList != null)
                {
                    wordInteropMethods.CreateMailistPrintAndOrSave(documentName,
                        mailboxList, addDateToFileName, addDateToTitle, save, print);
                }
            }

            psStatus.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

### ApartmentNumberVerifier.cs

This form presents only a textbox and a button. It is called prior to calling either the Add or Edit Tenant Dialog or the Delete Tenant Dialog. The purpose of the dialog is to find the correct tenant by apartment number.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class ApartmentNumberVerifier : Form
    {
        public enum NextActionEnum
        {
            ADD,
            DELETE,
            EDIT
        }

        public int ApartmentNumber;
        public Tenant TenantData { get; private set; }
        public NextActionEnum NextAction { get; set; }

        public ApartmentNumberVerifier()
        {
            TenantData = null;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void APV_FindApartment_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerifyApartmentNumber();
        }

        private void ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ANV_FindApartment_BTN.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void ApartmentNumberVerifier_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ANV_FindApartment_BTN.Enabled = false;
            ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB_KeyDown);
        }

        private void ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                VerifyApartmentNumber();
            }
        }

        private void ErrorActions(string errorMessage)
        {
            ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
            ActiveControl = ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB;
        }

        private bool ReportErrors(int aptNumber, PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid validApartmentId)
        {
            bool hasErrors = false;
            string errorMessage = null;

            switch (validApartmentId)
            {
                case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NONNUMERIC:
                    errorMessage = "Please enter a number in the box.";
                    break;

                case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_OUT_OF_RANGE:
                    int minAptNo = Globals.Complex.MinApartmentNumber;
                    int maxAptNo = Globals.Complex.MaxApartmentNumber;
                    errorMessage = "The apartment number: " + aptNumber.ToString() +
                        " is out of range[" + minAptNo.ToString() +
                        ", " + maxAptNo.ToString() + "] please enter a valid apartment number.";
                    break;

                case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NOT_FOUND:
                    errorMessage = "The number entered: " + aptNumber +
                        " was not found in the list of apartments.";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                ErrorActions(errorMessage);
                hasErrors = true;
            }

            return hasErrors;
        }

        private void VerifyApartmentNumber()
        {
            int aptNumber = 0;
            PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid validApartmentId =
                Globals.Complex.VerifyApartmentNumber(ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB.Text, out aptNumber);

            if (ReportErrors(aptNumber, validApartmentId))
            {
                return;
            }

            ExecuteNextgAction(aptNumber);
            Close();
        }

        private void ExecuteNextgAction(int aptNumber)
        {
            TenantData = Globals.TenantRoster.GetTenant(aptNumber);

            switch (NextAction)
            {
                case NextActionEnum.EDIT:
                case NextActionEnum.ADD:
                    AddOrEditResidentDlg addNewResident = new AddOrEditResidentDlg();
                    addNewResident.CurrentTenant = TenantData;
                    addNewResident.ApartmentNumber = aptNumber;
                    addNewResident.Show();
                    break;

                case NextActionEnum.DELETE:
                    DeleteRenterDlg deleteRenter_dlg = new DeleteRenterDlg();
                    deleteRenter_dlg.CurrentTenant = TenantData;
                    deleteRenter_dlg.ApartmentNumber = aptNumber;
                    deleteRenter_dlg.Show();
                    break;

                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Programmer error: NextAction = " +
                        NextAction.ToString() +
                        " this action is not implemented.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### AddOrEditResidentDlg.cs

This form allows the data in the excel file to be changed by either adding or editing the tenant information. This changes are saved in the TenantDataTable until the user either clicks the Save button or the Quit button. Both actions will save the data to the Excel spreadsheet.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class AddOrEditResidentDlg : Form
    {
        public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
        public Tenant CurrentTenant { get; set; }

        public AddOrEditResidentDlg()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ANR_SaveNewTenant_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentTenant.LastName = ANR_TenantLastName_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.FirstName = ANR_TenantFirstName_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.LeaseStart = ANR_MoveInDate_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.LeaseEnd = ANR_LeaseEnd_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.HomePhone = ANR_HomePhone_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.CoTenantLastName = ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.CoTenantFirstName = ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.RentersInsurancePolicy = ANR_RenterInsurance_TB.Text;
            CurrentTenant.Email = ANR_AlternateContact_TB.Text;
            Globals.TenantRoster.AddEditTenant(ApartmentNumber, CurrentTenant);
            Close();
        }

        private void AddNewResident_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetUpApartmentAddressLabel();
            ANR_SaveNewTenant_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
            ANR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (CurrentTenant != null)
            {
                ANR_TenantLastName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LastName;
                ANR_TenantFirstName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.FirstName;
                ANR_HomePhone_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.HomePhone;
                ANR_MoveInDate_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LeaseStart;
                ANR_LeaseEnd_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LeaseEnd;
                ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.CoTenantLastName;
                ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.CoTenantFirstName;
                ANR_AlternateContact_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.Email;
                ANR_RenterInsurance_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.RentersInsurancePolicy;
            }
        }

        private void SetUpApartmentAddressLabel()
        {
            string apartmentFullAddress = ApartmentNumber.ToString();
            string buildingAddress =
                Globals.Complex.FindBuildingByApartment(ApartmentNumber);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingAddress))
            {
                apartmentFullAddress = buildingAddress + " Apartment " + ApartmentNumber.ToString();
                ANR_ApartmentNumber_Label.Text = apartmentFullAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                ANR_ApartmentNumber_Label.Text = "Apartment Number:      " + apartmentFullAddress;
            }
            ANR_ApartmentNumber_Label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        private void ANR_Cancel_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

### DeleteRenterDlg.cs

This form allow sht user to delete a tenant from the apartment complex. The changes are also stored in the TenantDataTable.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class DeleteRenterDlg : Form
    {
        public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
        public Tenant CurrentTenant { get; set; }

        public DeleteRenterDlg()
        {
            ApartmentNumber = 0;
            CurrentTenant = null;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DR_DeleteRenter_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.TenantRoster.DeleteTenant(ApartmentNumber);
            Close();
        }

        private void DeleteRenter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ApartmentNumber != 0 && CurrentTenant != null)
            {
                SetUpApartmentAddressLabel();
                DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.Enabled = false;
                DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
                DR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
                DR_TenantName_TB.Enabled = false;

                DR_TenantName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.mergedName();
            }
        }

        private void SetUpApartmentAddressLabel()
        {
            string apartmentFullAddress = ApartmentNumber.ToString();
            string buildingAddress =
                Globals.Complex.FindBuildingByApartment(ApartmentNumber);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingAddress))
            {
                apartmentFullAddress = buildingAddress + " Apartment " + ApartmentNumber.ToString();
                DR_AptNumber_LAB.Text = apartmentFullAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                DR_AptNumber_LAB.Text = "Apartment Number:      " + apartmentFullAddress;
            }
            DR_AptNumber_LAB.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        }



        private void DR_Renter2DeleteYes_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.Enabled = true;
            DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
            DR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void DR_Renter2DeleteNo_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.Enabled = false;
            DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
            DR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

        private void DR_Cancel_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

### ReportCurrentStatusWindow.cs

This form is used to present information to the user about the current status of the program it is only used during operations that can take noticible time such as reading the excel data file or writing the updates to the excel data file.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TenantRosterAutomation
{
    public partial class ReportCurrentStatusWindow : Form
    {
        public string MessageText { get; set; }
        public ReportCurrentStatusWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_CurrentProgressStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CPS_Message_TB.Text = MessageText;
            CPS_Message_TB.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(CPS_Message_TB.Text, CPS_Message_TB.Font);
            Height = (size.Height * 3) + 84;
            Width = size.Width + 84;
            CPS_Message_TB.Width = size.Width;
            CPS_Message_TB.Height = size.Height * 3;
            CPS_Message_TB.Left = 40;
            CPS_Message_TB.Height = 40;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider MVP pattern. Use data bindings? `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Also take care about field/property names: `Snake_Case` is not a thing to use in C#. Avoid absolute pixel-sizing or pixel-positioning, use panels like FlowLayoutPanel/TableLayoutPanel to arrange the UI components instead.

Comment: @aepot Write it up as an answer and get +1 and probably accepted.

Comment: It doesn't look like review but a couple of tips. I'm not ready to post the whole review, sorry. You may also create a self-answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `RentRosterApp`

- If you have read any of my reviews then you know I do value consistent naming

  - Here I can see occasional abbreviations which does not help legibility

    - `..._Button_Click` vs `..._BTN_Click`
    - `ApartmentNumberVerifier` vs `EditPreferencesDlg`
    - `EditPreferences_...` vs `RR_Quit_...`
- The `Load` method can be greatly simplified

```
private void RentRosterApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RR_Quit_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;
    if (globalsInitialized) return; //early exit

    SetButtonsEnablement(false);

    using (EditPreferencesDlg preferences_dlg = new EditPreferencesDlg())
        if (preferences_dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            SetButtonsEnablement(true);
}

private void SetButtonsEnablement(bool isEnabled)
{
    PrintMailboxLists_Button.Enabled = isEnabled;
    AddNewResident_Button.Enabled = isEnabled;
    DeleteRenter_Button.Enabled = isEnabled;
}
```

- Inside the `Load` method you have used `using` around `EditPreferencesDlg` whereas in `EditPreferences_BTN_Click` you haven't
- You can extract the common part for the `RR` button event handlers into a separate method

```
private void RR_Quit_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SafeExcelCall(() =>
    {
        Globals.Save();
        Globals.ReleaseAllModels();
        Close();
    });
}

private void RR_SAVEEDITS_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SafeExcelCall(Globals.SaveTenantData);
}

//Since I don't know your domain I can't find a really good name here
//Usually we prefix a method with `SafeXYZ` if it handles `XYZ` exceptions 
private void SafeExcelCall(Action excelCall)
{
    try
    {
        excelCall();
    }
    catch (AlreadyOpenInExcelException ao)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ao.Message);
    }
}
```

#### `EditPreferencesDlg`

- I don't see the need why do we need `using` block around this form

  - *Please note that I haven't used WinForms in the last 10 years so I might be wrong on `using`*
- The Load method's switch statement can be rewritten like this to avoid repetitive code

```
RadioButton shouldBeCheckedRB;
switch (localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions)
{
    case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave:
        shouldBeCheckedRB = EP_PrintAndSave_RB;
        break;
    case PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly:
        shouldBeCheckedRB = EP_SavelOnly_RB;
        break;
    default:
        shouldBeCheckedRB = EP_PrintOnly_RB;
        break;
}
shouldBeCheckedRB.Checked = true;
```

- Or if you can use switch expression (depending on your C# version) then you can end up with an even more concise code

```
RadioButton shouldBeCheckedRB = localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions switch
{
    PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave => EP_PrintAndSave_RB,
    PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly => EP_SavelOnly_RB,
    _ => EP_PrintOnly_RB,
};
shouldBeCheckedRB.Checked = true;
```

- Yet again if you want to reduce the repetitive code of your `XYZ_CheckedChanged` handlers then you can do the following

```
private void EP_PrintAndSave_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => SetPrintSaveOptions(PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave);

private void EP_SavelOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => SetPrintSaveOptions(PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly);  

private void EP_PrintOnly_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => SetPrintSaveOptions(PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly);

private void SetPrintSaveOptions(PrintSavePreference.PrintSave option)
    => localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions = option;
```

- Or you define a mapping between the RadioButtons and the PrintSave values and then dynamically specify the event handlers (for example inside Load)

```
Dictionary<RadioButtion, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave> mappings = new Dictionary<RadioButtion, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave>
{
    { EP_PrintAndSave_RB, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave },
    { EP_SavelOnly_RB, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly },
    { EP_PrintOnly_RB, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly }
};

foreach (var mapping in mappings)
{
    mapping.Key.CheckedChanged += (s, e) =>
        localPreferences.PrintSaveOptions = mapping.Value;
}
```

- `findDefaultFolderLocationExecute`: this does not follow your snake casing naming
- Once again the naming of your variables are inconsistent

  - `findDefaultFolderLocationExecute`'s `fbd` vs `findTenantRosterExcelFile`'s `FindTenantRoster`
- Minor but you can use object initializer to reduce the initialization code

```
var FindTenantRoster = new OpenFileDialog()
{ 
    InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
    Filter = "Excel Files| *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm"
};
```

- And here comes my favourite control name: `EP_RentRosterSheetName_LISTBOX`
- Please try to consolidate your variables names as well (`ExcelFile` vs `sheetNames`)
- You can reduce the level of indention of the `fillSheetSelectorListBox` method by using early exits

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec))
    return; 
            
var excelFile = new ExcelFileData(
    localPreferences.ExcelWorkBookFullFileSpec,
    localPreferences.ExcelWorkSheetName);
List<string> sheetNames = excelFile.GetWorkSheetCollection();
            
if (sheetNames == null)
    return;
```

---

#### `PrintMailboxListsDlg`

- Inside the Load please prefer `AddRange` over multiple `Add` method calls

```
SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.Items.AddRange(Globals.Complex.BuildingAddressList);
SelectBuilding2Print_listBox.Items.Add("All Buildings");
```

- If you move the `CheckedChanged` handlers inside the `Load` method then those piece of code that are related to each other (high cohesion) then they are next to each other

```
AddDateToFileName_CB.Checked = addDateToFileName;
AddDateToFileName_CB.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => addDateToFileName = !addDateToFileName;

AddDateUnderAddress_CB.Checked = addDateToTitle;
AddDateUnderAddress_CB.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => addDateToTitle = !addDateToTitle;
```

- Inside the `PML_SaveAndPrint_Button_Click` you are using the same hard-coded string (`"All Buildings"`) as you have used in the Load

  - Please prefer class level constants
- `String.Compare(...) == 0` could be replaced with `string.Equals`

```
string.Equals(selectedBuildings, allBuildings)
```

- The `printAndOrSaveMailList` could be rewritten in a way that the core functionality is on the top indentation level

```
private void PrintAndOrSaveMailList(string streetAddress)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(streetAddress, out int streetNumber))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Non Numeric string passed into PrintMailboxLists_Form::printAndOrSaveMailList().");
        return;
    }

    PrintAndOrSaveMailList(streetNumber);
}
```

- BTW this `iStreetNumber` does sound like an apple product :)

  - Since the `number` suffix already indicates the data type I would not recommend to prefix it with `i`
- Inside your `SelectBuilding2Print_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged` method I don't think that null check is needed

  - At least based on my intuition a listbox will not fire an selected index changed event for a `null` item
- Inside your `PrintAndOrSaveMailList` I think you have overcomplicated the two bool variables' assignment

```
bool save = printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave
    || printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly;
bool print = printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave
    || printSave == PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly;
```

- Or with Linq you can write something like this

```
bool save = new[] { PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.SaveOnly }.Contains(printSave);
bool print = new[] { PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintAndSave, PrintSavePreference.PrintSave.PrintOnly }.Contains(printSave);
```

- For string concatenations please prefer string interpolation or StringBuilder instead of `+` or `+=` operators
- If you want to you get rid of one level of indentation at the end of this method then you can change the `mailboxList` assignment like this

```
Building building = Globals.Complex.GetBuilding(streetAddress);
MailboxData mailboxList = building != null ? Globals.Complex.GetMailBoxList(building) : null;

if (mailboxList != null)
{
    wordInteropMethods.CreateMailistPrintAndOrSave(documentName,
        mailboxList, addDateToFileName, addDateToTitle, save, print);
}
```

---

#### `ApartmentNumberVerifier`

- If you follow the [C# naming convention for enums](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229043(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#capitalization-rules-for-identifiers) then you should end up with this

```
public enum NextAction
{
    Add,
    Delete,
    Edit
}
```

- It is perfectly normal to have properties like this

```
public NextAction NextAction { get; set; }
```

- Inside your `ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB_KeyDown` please prefer early exit over guard expression to streamline the method's implementation

```
private void ANV_ApartmentNumber_TB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
        return;
            
    VerifyApartmentNumber();
}
```

- The `ReportError` can be written in so many different ways, let me show two
- A) With switch statement + `hasError` re-assignment in default case

```
bool hasError = true;
string errorMessage = null;
switch (validApartmentId)
{
    case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NONNUMERIC:
        errorMessage = "Please enter a number in the box.";
        break;
    case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_OUT_OF_RANGE:
        errorMessage = $"The apartment number: {aptNumber} is out of range[{Globals.Complex.MinApartmentNumber}, {Globals.Complex.MaxApartmentNumber}] please enter a valid apartment number.";
        break;
    case PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NOT_FOUND:
        errorMessage = $"The number entered: {aptNumber} was not found in the list of apartments.";
        break;
    default:
        hasError = false;
        break;
}

if (hasError)
    ErrorActions(errorMessage);

return hasError;
```

- B) With switch expression + `hasError` calculation after switch

```
string errorMessage = validApartmentId switch
{
    PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NONNUMERIC =>
        "Please enter a number in the box.",
    PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_OUT_OF_RANGE =>
        $"The apartment number: {aptNumber} is out of range[{Globals.Complex.MinApartmentNumber}, {Globals.Complex.MaxApartmentNumber}] please enter a valid apartment number.",
    PropertyComplex.ApartmentNumberValid.APARTMENT_NUMBER_NOT_FOUND =>
        $"The number entered: {aptNumber} was not found in the list of apartments.",
    _ => null
};
       
var hasError = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage);
if (hasError)
    ErrorActions(errorMessage);

return hasError;
```

- `ExecuteNextgAction`: I assume the `g` is just a typo here
- If you want to execute more than a single line in each `case` branch (+ `break`) then prefer to use code block `{}` statement

```
case NextActionEnum.Add:
    {
        AddOrEditResidentDlg addNewResident = new AddOrEditResidentDlg();
        addNewResident.CurrentTenant = TenantData;
        addNewResident.ApartmentNumber = aptNumber;
        addNewResident.Show();
        break;
    }
```

- Or try to convert your multiline block into a single statement if possible

```
case NextAction.Add:
    new AddOrEditResidentDlg()
    {
        CurrentTenant = TenantData,
        ApartmentNumber = aptNumber
    }.Show();
    break;
```

---

#### `AddOrEditResidentDlg`

- As you have already seen I'm not a huge fan of a repetitive code

  - When I saw here the manual DataBinding between the TextBoxes and the `Tenant` object I though I can come up with an easier solution
  - I did, but it relies on building expression trees dynamically which needs a bit more explanation than simply just sharing it with you
  - So, I decided to make another post with that code
- The `SetUpApartmentAddressLabel` method can be greatly simplified, where there is no need for the `if`-`else` blocks and for the `apartmentFullAddress` variable

```
string buildingAddress =
    Globals.Complex.FindBuildingByApartment(ApartmentNumber);

ANR_ApartmentNumber_Label.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingAddress)
    ? $"Apartment Number:      {ApartmentNumber}"
    : $"{buildingAddress} Apartment {ApartmentNumber}";

ANR_ApartmentNumber_Label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
```

#### `DeleteRenterDlg`

- Inside the ctor you don't need to initialize the `CurrentTenant` with `null`, since that's the default value for reference types

  - Same applies for `ApartmentNumber` where the default value is 0
- By the way it seems a bit unsafe that you do not perform any checks on the `ApartmentNumber` property before you call the `DeleteTenant`
- Inside the `Load` method you can use the [`default` operator/literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) to check the properties' values

```
//prior C# 7.1
if (ApartmentNumber != default(int) && CurrentTenant != default(Tenant))
//since C# 7.1 we can use default literal
if (ApartmentNumber != default && CurrentTenant != default)
```

- Yet again please prefer early exit instead of guard expression

```
if (ApartmentNumber == default || CurrentTenant == default)
    return;
            
SetUpApartmentAddressLabel();
...
```

- The `SetUpApartmentAddressLabel` can be simplified in the same way as I suggested it for the `AddOrEditResidentDlg` class
- You can combine the `DR_Renter2DeleteYes_RB_CheckedChanged` and  `DR_Renter2DeleteNo_RB_CheckedChanged` event handlers into one:

```
private void DR_Renter2Delete_RB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    var canBeDeleted = string.Equals(rb.Name, nameof(DR_Renter2DeleteYes_RB));

    DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.Enabled = canBeDeleted;
    DR_DeleteRenter_BTN.BackColor = canBeDeleted ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    DR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = canBeDeleted ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
}
```

---

#### `ReportCurrentStatusWindow`

- Either call the property `Text` or `Message`, you don't need to use both

  - It's like you name your warning label, which is very important to `WarningVeryImporantInformationLabel`
  - Either `WarningLabel` or `ImportantInfoLabel` would be sufficient
- `<sarcasm>` I love magic numbers `</sarcasm>`

  - They can break your application really easily if you don't pay enough attention
  - A better way can be the utilization of constants

```
const int WindowMargin = 84;
const int MessageTBMargin = 40;
const int HeightMultipler = 3;

private void Form_CurrentProgressStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPS_Message_TB.Text = MessageText;
    CPS_Message_TB.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(CPS_Message_TB.Text, CPS_Message_TB.Font);

    Height = (size.Height * HeightMultipler) + WindowMargin;
    Width = size.Width + WindowMargin;
    CPS_Message_TB.Width = size.Width;
    CPS_Message_TB.Height = size.Height * HeightMultipler;
    CPS_Message_TB.Left = MessageTBMargin;
    CPS_Message_TB.Height = MessageTBMargin; //Did you mean Top?
}
```

- By the way you are setting the `CPS_Message_TB.Height` twice

  - I suppose you wanted to set the `Top` property instead

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough review, I look forward to any continuation.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I will try to finish my review at the end of tomorrow.

Comment: Re: `I don't see the need why do we need using block around this form ` You are correct, there is no reason for a `using` block here although there might be good reason for a `try {} catch() {}` block.

Comment: Wow, [23 new issues](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/Anza-Tenant-Roster/issues) in the issues list. I've closed one because I won't address it. If you want to see how seriously I take code reviews look at the list. Old C/C++ programming habits for the names of the enums and the lack of class constants for strings, I will fix those. It is amazing how many good practices you ignore when you are in a rush for a deadline.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I can see your dedication, awesome. I've updated my post please check the new observations as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've already left a fairly lengthy post where I have detailed most of my observations.

Here I want to focus only on the `AddOrEditResidentDlg` class's DataBinding thingy.

As I said I'm not a huge fan of the repetitive code like these:

```
CurrentTenant.LastName = ANR_TenantLastName_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.FirstName = ANR_TenantFirstName_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.LeaseStart = ANR_MoveInDate_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.LeaseEnd = ANR_LeaseEnd_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.HomePhone = ANR_HomePhone_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.CoTenantLastName = ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.CoTenantFirstName = ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.RentersInsurancePolicy = ANR_RenterInsurance_TB.Text;
CurrentTenant.Email = ANR_AlternateContact_TB.Text;
```

```
ANR_TenantLastName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LastName;
ANR_TenantFirstName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.FirstName;
ANR_HomePhone_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.HomePhone;
ANR_MoveInDate_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LeaseStart;
ANR_LeaseEnd_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.LeaseEnd;
ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.CoTenantLastName;
ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.CoTenantFirstName;
ANR_AlternateContact_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.Email;
ANR_RenterInsurance_TB.Text = CurrentTenant.RentersInsurancePolicy;
```

Basically it is a TwoWay binding between your `CurrentTenant` property and your `TextBox`es. I don't want to convince you here to use DataBinding rather I would like to show you a programatic way to do that.

---

So, the above code basically says which property of the `Tenant` object is connected to the which `TextBox`'s `Text`. If we can define a mapping then we can use that information in both directions. Fortunately we can :) In order to specify a property selector all you need is a simple `Func` like this:

```
Func<Tenant, string>
```

It says if I receive a `Tenant` instance I will return a `string`. All of the following lambda expressions are satisfy this requirement:

```
ct => ct.LastName
ct => ct.FirstName
...
ct => ct.Email
```

Great, we can define the mapping for example via a `Dictionary`

```
static readonly Dictionary<Func<Tenant, string>, TextBox> mappings = new Dictionary<Func<Tenant, string>, TextBox>
{
    { ct => ct.LastName, ANR_TenantLastName_TB },
    { ct => ct.FirstName, ANR_TenantFirstName_TB },
    { ct => ct.LeaseStart, ANR_MoveInDate_TB },
    { ct => ct.LeaseEnd, ANR_LeaseEnd_TB },
    { ct => ct.HomePhone, ANR_HomePhone_TB },
    { ct => ct.CoTenantLastName, ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB },
    { ct => ct.CoTenantFirstName, ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB },
    { ct => ct.RentersInsurancePolicy, ANR_RenterInsurance_TB },
    { ct => ct.Email, ANR_AlternateContact_TB }
};
```

We are almost good, but we need to create assignment expressions dynamically, so we need to use `Expression<Func<Tenant, string>>` instead of `Func<Tenant, string>`. The good news is that we only need to change the Dictionary's type but we don't have to touch the collection initializer.

```
static readonly Dictionary<Expression<Func<Tenant, string>>, TextBox> mappings = new Dictionary<Expression<Func<Tenant, string>>, TextBox>
{
    { ct => ct.LastName, ANR_TenantLastName_TB },
    { ct => ct.FirstName, ANR_TenantFirstName_TB },
    { ct => ct.LeaseStart, ANR_MoveInDate_TB },
    { ct => ct.LeaseEnd, ANR_LeaseEnd_TB },
    { ct => ct.HomePhone, ANR_HomePhone_TB },
    { ct => ct.CoTenantLastName, ANR_CoTenantLastName_TB },
    { ct => ct.CoTenantFirstName, ANR_AdditionalOccupantFirstName_TB },
    { ct => ct.RentersInsurancePolicy, ANR_RenterInsurance_TB },
    { ct => ct.Email, ANR_AlternateContact_TB }
};
```

---

Now let's see how can we make use of this.

Let's start with the update `Tenant` property with a `TextBox`'s Text value

```
private void UpdateCurrentTenantWithTextBoxValue(Expression<Func<Tenant, string>> propertySelector, TextBox textBox)
{
    var stringParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
    Expression<Func<TextBox, string>> textSelector = tb => tb.Text;

    var assignment = Expression.Lambda<Action<Tenant, string>>(
        Expression.Assign(propertySelector.Body, stringParameter),
        propertySelector.Parameters[0], stringParameter);

    var textBoxTextValue = textSelector.Compile()(textBox);
    assignment.Compile()(CurrentTenant, textBox.Text);
}
```

- The two parameters of this method are nicely aligned with the Dictionary's `Key` and `Value`
- First we create a `ParameterExpression` where we are stating that our dynamically created assignment expression would require a string parameter (the new value)
- Then we define a property selector for a `TextBox`

  - Here we specify that we want to use the `Text` property of the given `TextBox` instance
- Then we define our assignment expression

  - You should think about this as a method which receives two parameters (a `Tenant` and a `string`) and then performs the assignment

```
(Tenant t, string newValue) => propertySelector(t) = newValue;
```

- I would not go into the details why this expression was built up like this (if you don't mind)
- Finally get the actual value of the `TextBox`'s `Text` by complying and executing the `textSelector`

  - So, the `textBoxTextValue` contains the actual value of the `textBox` parameter's `Text`
- We need to compile and execute the assignment as well where we specify its parameters

  - So, basically the above assignment expression is called like this

```
assignment(CurrentTenant, textSelector(textBox))
```

---

With this tool in our hand we can simplify the `ANR_SaveNewTenant_BTN_Click` method like this

```
private void ANR_SaveNewTenant_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var mapping in mappings)
        UpdateCurrentTenantWithTextBoxValue(mapping.Key, mapping.Value);

    Globals.TenantRoster.AddEditTenant(ApartmentNumber, CurrentTenant);
    Close();
}
```

The other direction can be also greatly simplified as well

```
private void AddNewResident_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetUpApartmentAddressLabel();
    ANR_SaveNewTenant_BTN.BackColor = Color.Green;
    ANR_Cancel_BTN.BackColor = Color.Red;

    if (CurrentTenant == null)
        return;

    foreach (var mapping in mappings)
        UpdateTextBoxWithCurrentTenantValue(mapping.Value, mapping.Key);
}
```

Let's see the code of the `UpdateTextBoxWithCurrentTenantValue`

```
private static void UpdateTextBoxWithCurrentTenantValue(TextBox textBox, Expression<Func<Tenant, string>> propertySelector)
{
    var stringParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
    Expression<Func<TextBox, string>> textSelector = tb => tb.Text;
    var assignment = Expression.Lambda<Action<TextBox, string>>(
        Expression.Assign(textSelector.Body, stringParameter),
        textSelector.Parameters[0], stringParameter);

    var tenantFieldValue = propertySelector.Compile()(CurrentTenant);
    assignment.Compile()(textBox, tenantFieldValue);
}
```

- It is the symmetric counterpart of the previous method
- Here I've change the order of the parameters because for me it makes more sense

  - But feel free to keep the parameter ordering as the other one if you wish
- The only difference here is the assignment expression

```
(TextBox tb, string newValue) => textSelector(tb) = newValue;
```

- The actual call of this expression look like this

```
assignment(textBox, propertySelector(CurrentTenant))
```

---

As you can see the `ParameterExpression` and the `textSelector` can be easily extracted from both methods

```
private static ParameterExpression StringParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
private static Expression<Func<TextBox, string>> TextSelector = tb => tb.Text;

private void UpdateCurrentTenantWithTextBoxValue(Expression<Func<Tenant, string>> propertySelector, TextBox textBox)
{
    var assignment = Expression.Lambda<Action<Tenant, string>>(
        Expression.Assign(propertySelector.Body, StringParameter),
        propertySelector.Parameters[0], StringParameter);

    var textBoxTextValue = TextSelector.Compile()(textBox);
    assignment.Compile()(CurrentTenant, textBox.Text);
}

private static void UpdateTextBoxWithCurrentTenantValue(TextBox textBox, Expression<Func<Tenant, string>> propertySelector)
{
    var assignment = Expression.Lambda<Action<TextBox, string>>(
        Expression.Assign(TextSelector.Body, StringParameter),
        TextSelector.Parameters[0], StringParameter);

    var tenantFieldValue = propertySelector.Compile()(CurrentTenant);
    assignment.Compile()(textBox, tenantFieldValue);
}
```

I know this solution is more complex than a simple databinding and it requires a bit more advanced C# skills but it does work. It is an alternative feel free to give it a try.

Comment: @aepot nice catch, thanks mate

Comment: I may have to change the accepted answer, definitely interesting.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'm glad that you have found it interesting. :)